# onClickListener for YouTubePlayer

Tags: android, android-layout, youtube-api, onclicklistener, android-touch-event

I want to add an onClickListener event for YouTube Player API 
I tried many many solutions but all of them didn't work

Some of my attempts

```
    YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = findViewById(R.id.youtubePlayer);
    youTubePlayerView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            Log.d(TAG,"onClick");
        }
    });
```

---

```
    YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = findViewById(R.id.youtubePlayer);
    youTubePlayerView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
        {
            Log.d(TAG,"onTouch");
            return false;
        }
    });
```

---

Also, I tried to add a layout above the YouTube player view and make it transparent then add a click listener to this layout but the player stops after few seconds every time

And my last attempt was working with GestureDetector class but also didn't work

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I tried to add a layout above the YouTube player view and make it
>   transparent then add a click listener to this layout but the player
>   stops after few seconds*

`YouTube Player API` does not allow any view above it be it a visible or not and will close with an [ErrorReason](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason).

It also consumes any and all touch events without sharing them. However you can **`Override`** `dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent)` method of the parent `ViewGroup` to the `YouTubePlayerView`and *steal* back these touch events to kick you own `onClick()` callback.

What you have to do is, first create a container in the xml layout file where you've placed your `YouTubePlayerView`.

**youtube_player_view_layout.xml**

```
<MyCustomFrameLayout>
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    <YouTubePlayerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
    </YouTubePlayerView>
</MyCustomFrameLayout>
```

`MyCustomFrameLayout` must be added with fully qualified name in layout xml i.e. with **[my.class.package]+[ClassName]**

**MyCustomFrameLayout.java**

```
public class MyCustomFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {

    private boolean actionDownReceived = false;
    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                actionDownReceived = true;
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                // No longer a click, probably a gesture.
                actionDownReceived = false;
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                if (actionDownReceived) {
                    performClick();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

and then all you need to do is set click listener on `MyCustomFrameLayout`.

> **Disclaimer :** *The above code is not tested in an IDE and will probably not run correctly if/when copied as is. However the essence
>   of the thought is properly projected here*.

Comment: Great idea! I had to add "debounce time" check because ACTION_MOVE was being fired almost every time before ACTION_UP: something like (inside case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: { if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTouch > 100) {
                    actionDownReceived = false
                }